# Would replacing ' :: ' with ' . ' create ambiguities in C++?

Tags: c++, language-design

In C++, the operator `::` is used to access classes, functions and variables in a namespace or class.

If the language specification used `.` instead of `::` in those cases too like when accessing instance variables/methods of an object then would that cause possible ambiguities that aren't present with `::`?

Given that C++ doesn't allow variable names that are also a type name, I can't think of a case where that could happen.

Clarification: I'm not asking why `::` was chosen over `.`, just if it could have worked too?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207134/discussion-on-question-by-jimmy-r-t-would-replacing-with-create-am).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Due to attempts to make C++ mostly compatible with the existing C code (which allows name collisions between object names and struct tags), C++ allows name collisions between class names and object names.

Which means that:

```
struct data {
    static int member;
};

struct data2 {
    int member;
};

void f(data2& data) {
    data.member = data::member;
}
```

is legit code.

Comment: So the answer to the question in the title is _Yes, it would_, isn't it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis it's not that simple. Were C++ developed as a completely new language, like Java or C#, the ambiguity _could probably be avoidable_. But C++ was developed as "C with classes", and that's why it's not. "Yes, it _will_" is a correct answer, but to a different question.

Comment: Wait, isn't the assignment line just showing that putting `.` or `::` between the same two "words" has different effect (`data.member` refers to the `member` of the `data` object of class `data2`, whereas `data::member` refers to the `member` of the class `data`)?

Comment: Yes, but it's not something that language designers should be proud of. It's just an artifact of compatibility decisions.

Comment: Ok, I understand that how C++ is today and has been so far (also) depends on what C was at the time C++ developed from it. But talking of C++ as it is, and leaving aside why it is as it is, there would an ambiguity if all `::` were changed to `.`. In a way you answered _yes_ already. I simply cannot breach into you first comment. Maybe my level makes that comment look smoky to me.

Comment: The "compatibiliy decision" *is* something that the language designers are very particular about. Not always so about the outcome, but the principle has been very important in the success of C++.

Answer (score 38):

An example where both are valid, but refer to different objects:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
};

struct B {
    int i;
    A B;
};

int main() {
    B x {0, 1};
    std::cout << x.B.i << '\n';
    std::cout << x.B::i << '\n';
}
```

See [live on coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40e03237388e7c59).

Comment: And this one *couldn't* be easily resolved with different design decisions!

Answer (score 7):

There is difference between `a::b` and `a.b` where `::` implies that `a` used as namespace, which means that it is namespace or typename. Provided that C++ supports non-virtual plural inheritance and that a variable can have same name as a type, this strips chances of referencing wrong object. It's necessary for template metaprogramming.

Another example would be `&B::foo` vs `&B.foo` in context of class B.

Answer (score 2):

Let extend @Deduplicator example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
};

struct B : public A {
    int i;
    A A;
};

int main() {
    B x {1, 2};
    std::cout << x.i << '\n';
    std::cout << x.B::i << '\n';  // The same as the line above.
    std::cout << x.A.i << '\n';
    std::cout << x.A::i << '\n';  // Not the same as the line above.
}
```

[Live on Coliru Viewer](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95a779f9e087dbc6)

Not having a possibility to differentiate with help of ::, which member we want to access, it is impossible to access members declared in a parent class with identical names.

Comment: `A A` (variable name that is also a type name) isn't valid in C++ though, so this example doesn't work for now

Comment: @JimmyR.T. There is the working life example on Coliru Viewer. Confirm your statement please with a paragraph from the standard.

Comment: if one would add the cursed  inheritance diamond here with same thing on other side, it would be a pinnacle of naming schizophrenia possible in C++